# How can I create a view using the E4 programming model to be a plug-in for Eclipse 4.2 or above?

Tags: eclipse, e4

Most of the existing Eclipse plug-ins use the extension registry and subclasses of `ViewPart`, coupled with the compatibility layer. As a result, writing a new view (especially using the new plug-in wizard in PDE) results in plug-ins that look like:

```
<plugin>
  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
    <view name="Example View" class="org.example.ExampleView"/>
  </extension>
</plugin>

public class ExampleView extends ViewPart {
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to take advantage of the E4 programming model to create a view like:

```
public class Example {
  @Inject
  public Example(Composite parent) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and have that hooked into an existing Eclipse 4.2 instance, so that it shows up in the 'Show View' menu? If so, how is it declaratively wired in (since that the `LegacyIDE.e4xmi` is immutable and can't be added to).

Comment: I guess the question boils down to 'How can I declaratively register the MPartDescriptor without requiring either code to be executed or modification of a single XML file'. This seems essential if the plug-in is to be installed from an external update site into an existing Eclipse instance, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code I've written for the e4 model editor (http://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/org.eclipse.e4.tools.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.editor3x/src/org/eclipse/e4/tools/emf/editor3x).

I've a set of wrappers for this at http://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/org.eclipse.e4.tools.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat for 4.3 we plan on direct support.

Comment: Nice. Look forward to seeing the 4.3 implementation plan. Will it be backported to 4.2? Otherwise it will be in 4.4 when people will really start targeting this. By the way, there's a typo: http://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/org.eclipse.e4.tools.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat/src/org/eclipse/e4/tools/compat/internal/PartHelper.java#n60 should be 'create' not 'creat' :)